# Java: Any need to use sync gateway in web application for communicating with couchbase server?

Tags: java, couchbase, java-client, couchbase-sync-gateway, couchbase-java-api

I am new in couchDB database. I am trying to connect couchbase server using JAVA client, but I am confused in Couchbase sync gateway.

My question is, Couchbase sync gateway is only for mobile application or can we use for web application? is this required for web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand the concept of Couchbase mobile, It includes couchbase lite, couchbase sync gateway and further couchbase sync gateway uses couchbase server for storage, If you directly want to use couchbase server for your web app , you can use it through java sdk http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/java-intro.html

Comment: I have made a group here for couchbase related-stuff on stackoverflow, Please join there and invite others also

Answer (score 1):

The Sync Gateway can also be used for web application using it's REST API. But it is not required for a web app. You can use classic server SDKs too.

Comment: I was used the classic server SDK. but I am not able to connect it to the mobile. I mean My sync operation is not performed, it can't connects to the sync gateway.